# Scanning 2D String Array From a File

Tags: java, arrays, file, 2d

```
Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner (new File(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Puzzle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    int m = 4;
    int n = 4;
     Puzzle = new String [m][n];
    while (input.next()!=null){
        for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                Puzzle[i][j]= input.next();
                System.out.println(Puzzle[i][j]);
            }
        }   

    }
```

> I have a little problem with this piece of code. as I scan the input to put my puzzle array it skips the first string. for example in the first line, lets assume the 4 letter "A B C D" are on. It skips the "A" and continues with "B". I know maybe its too easy for you guys, but as a begginner I kinda need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are consuming multiple tokens in each iteration of the while loop - one when you call `next()` in the condition of the loop (which is not used) and multiple others when you call `next()` inside the for loops (which you store).

You should change the logic of your code. You don't need the while loop.

For example :

```
    boolean done = false;
    for (int i=0;i<m && !done;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<n && !done;j++){
            Puzzle[i][j]= input.next();
            if (Puzzle[i][j] == null)
                done = true;
            System.out.println(Puzzle[i][j]);
        }
    }
```